# Children objects validation, at least one with a given value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am implementing a quiz - like feature. Each quiz is composed of several questions, each question has 3 possible answers.

I need to ensure that for each question there is at least one correct answer.

My code looks like this:

`AssessmentQuestion.rb` (model)

```
has_many :assessment_options, inverse_of: :assessment_question, autosave: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assessment_options

(...)

validate :has_correct_answer

(...)

  def has_correct_answer
    errors.add(:question, "no correct answer") unless self.assessment_options.exists?(is_correct: true)
  end
```

Unfortunately this validation does not work - it raises an error ('no correct answer' even if there is an `assessment_option` with a correct answer.

**Update (answer for NM Pennypacker question):**

`AssessmentQuestionsController.rb`:

```
def new
    params[:course_id].present? ? edited_course : all_courses
    @assessment_question = AssessmentQuestion.new
        3.times {@assessment_question.assessment_options.build}
  end
```

```
  def create
    @assessment_question = AssessmentQuestion.new(assessment_question_params)
     if @assessment_question.save
       redirect_to course_path(assessment_question_params[:course_id]), notice: 'Assessment question was successfully created.'
     else
       params[:course_id].present? ? edited_course : all_courses
       render :new
     end
  end
```

`_form.htm.erb`

`assessment_options` are being added after

```
  <%= form.fields_for :assessment_options do |ao| %>
```

**Update (answer for Emilio Menéndez question):**

`assessment_question_params`:

```
    def assessment_question_params
      params.require(:assessment_question).permit(:id, :question, :course_id, :active,
        { assessment_options_attributes: [:id, :assessment_question_id, :answer, :is_correct] } )
    end
```

Comment: Care to share what the error is?

Comment: my custom validation error: 'no correct answer' :)

Comment: How are you trying to create/save/update the `AssessmentOption`?

Comment: @NMPennypacker i just build assessment_options and treat them as nested_attributes - problem description updated. Without this validation everything is saving without any issues :)

Comment: what's in `assessment_question_params`?

Comment: @EmilioMenéndez problem description updated. Any ideas why it is not working as i expect?

Comment: not sure but maybe you need to nest your `<%= form.fields_for :assessment_options do |ao| %>` like it the docs example? https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: What do you mean by "to nest my ..... " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is that following statement always returns false - probably because objects are not saved yet.

```
self.assessment_options.exists?(is_correct: true)
```

To solve this issue i had to modify has_correct_answer as follows:

```
  def has_correct_answer
    errors.add(:question, "no correct answer") unless self.assessment_options.select { |o| o.is_correct == true}.count > 0
  end
```

Any better idea / solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this recently as well in a `Rails 5.2` app. It seems `strong_parameters` isn't working with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as described in the docs here: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

In my case I had to swap out `my_model_attributes: []` for `my_model: []`, so in your case:

```
def assessment_question_params
  params.require(:assessment_question).permit(
    :id,
    :question,
    :course_id,
    :active,
    { 
      assessment_options: [
        :id,
        :assessment_question_id,
        :answer,
        :is_correct
      ]
    } 
  )
end
```

Comment: For sure there must be some issues with it. But....if i use assessment_options as you said (instead of assessment_options_attributes), i also have te remove accepts_nested_attributes_for :assessment_options from my model. But if i do it, i cannot use 3.times {@assessment_question.assessment_options.build} to build my form.... Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: `@assessment_question.assessment_options.build()` will work without `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as long as you have `has_one` or `has_many/belongs_to` associations in place. You'll have access to `assessment_question_params[:assessment_options]`, or at least that's how I do it

Comment: In my case when a remove accepts_nested_attributes @assessment_question.assessment_options.build() stops working (in my form i get 1 assessment_option build, not 3) - maybe after removing acceptes_nested_attributes i should do sth else to keep build method working? But finally I have found issues solution :)